# can I make google API that send email just from my email

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

Hi I am trying to make c# application that send email from my email to verity of users I want the program to send email just from my account do I have to make the full process of makeing the api that send email from a deferent users or there is a way to make a connection with just my email

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: thank you for your reply this is the old way of connecting gmail but google will stop this way in the end of these month now they want to make an project on google and connect with api

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off if you have a google workspace account. Then you could use a service account with domain wide deligation and delgate to a user on your domain. Then when you run your app it will be like that user is sending the emails.  For example create a noreply user on the domain and jsut send emails from them.

```
string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
            const string serviceAccount = "clawskeyboard-smtp@clawskeyboard-api.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\Creds.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var gsuiteUser = "noreply@yourdomain.com";

            var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
            {
                User = gsuiteUser,
                Scopes = new[] { GmailService.Scope.Gmail }

            }.FromCertificate(certificate);
```

If this is a standard gmail account as i suspect then things will be much harder.  First off you will need to set up oauth2 and authorize your app as yourself.  This can be done easy enough.

```
 UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/Creds.json");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }
        return credential;
```

Just remember to watch it though if the refresh token ever expires you will need to authorize it again.